# can a raspberry type powered controller device be successful in obtaining a geostationary orbit?

Tags: microgravity, geostationary

I am currently looking into the possibility of very tiny automated drone transportation. I hope to prove viability by testing using orbital mechanics experiments. Achieving geostationary orbit and successful reentry is the projects main goals.

Comment: The Shuttle's guidance computer was run by an AP-101 chip running at about 0.5 MIPS.  Raspberry Pi 3 does 2441 MIPS.  It'll run PEG just fine (until it gets zapped by radiation and dies).

Comment: wow that's amazing thanks for sharing! @lamont

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes. I've seen way less powerful hardware do it. Will it do it for long, no, that thing is going to be dead from radiation really quick. What rocket are you planning on using that has Delta-V to get there, and then get you back?